# Converting Type Int to Type Byte

Tags: c#, types, type-conversion

I have a small set of code that attempts to bit-shift a 1-bit from the 0 index to the 7 index in a byte. After each bit shift I want to take the int value and convert it to a byte:

```
for(int t=0; t<8; t++)
{
    int ShiftBit = 0x80 >> t;
    byte ShiftBitByte = Convert.ToByte(ShiftBit.ToString(),8);
}
```

I would expect the outputs to be:

- 0x80
- 0x40
- 0x20
- 0x10
- 0x08
- 0x04
- 0x02
- 0x01

When I run my code I encounter an exception "Additional non-parsable characters are at the end of the string." Is there a better way to capture these bytes?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just cast to byte or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't do you this?

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; ++i )
{
  int  s = 0x80 >> i ;
  byte b = (byte) s ;
)
```

Or (cleaner):

```
for ( int i = 0x00000080 ; i != 0 ; i >>1 )
{
  byte b = (byte) i ;
}
```

To turn a `byte` into a hex string, something like

```
byte b = ...
string s = string.Format("0x{0:X2}",b) ;
```

Ought to do you. But a `byte` is a *number*, it doesn't have a format (representation) until you turn it into a string a give it one.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I guess what I am really trying to do is shift a 1 as follows: 10000000 (or 0x80), 01000000 (or 0x40) .... 0x00000001 (or 0x01). Once each bit is shifted I want to capture it in hex format "0x--".

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the error because you are erroneously specifying that the string is in base 8.  The digit '8' is not a legal digit in base 8, which uses only 0 through 7.

Why not

```
for (byte b = 0x80; b != 0; b >>= 1)
```

?

> Thanks for catching that ... what I really meant to write was shift a bit in int 0x10000000 from index 0 to 7 and then convert it to a byte each time for an array [0x80, 0x40, 0x20, 0x10, 0x08, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01]. Is that possible?

I don't understand what int `0x10000000` has to do with it.  If you want that array, you can achieve that in any of a number of ways:

```
byte[] xs = { 0x80, 0x40, 0x20, 0x10, 0x08, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01 };

byte[] ys = Enumerable.Range(0, 8).Select(i => (byte)(0x80 >> i)).ToArray();

byte[] zs = new byte[8];
for (int index = 0; index < zs.Length; index++)
    zs[index] = (byte)(0x80 >> index);
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that ... what I really meant to write was shift a bit in int 0x10000000 from index 0 to 7 and then convert it to a byte each time for an array [0x80, 0x40, 0x20, 0x10, 0x08, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01]. Is that possible?

Comment: @Nevets I've updated my answer to address your question.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this ?

```
for (int t = 0; t < 8; t++)
{
   int ShiftBit = 0x80 >> t;
   byte ShiftBitByte = (byte) ShiftBit;

   Console.WriteLine("0x{0:X}",ShiftBitByte);
}
```

[image]

See [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)